# Singularity tries to grab wrong java

Tags: java, docker

We have a project that has traditionally been run via Docker.  Inside the docker build are many applications, including java.  Many of our customers need Singularity vs docker, so a Singularity image is created by pulling the docker image from docker hub, e.g.

singularity build phg_38.sif docker://maizegenetics/phg/0.0.38

The problem I'm having is the machine one which I test Singularity has java installed to:
/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java

Inside the docker (and in Singularity when I shell into it and check) java is at:
/usr/bin/java

when I run a program via Singularity which uses java ProcessBuilder to make a command line call, I get the error:

/liquibase/liquibase: line 91: /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java: No such file or directory

This tells me that Singularity is using the path to java from the machine, and not the java path that is inside the container.

I don't have this problem when I run via docker, only when I run the Singularity image created from Docker.

The script I'm running looks like this:

```
WORKING_DIR=/workdir/lcj34/liquibase_debug/
DOCKER_CONFIG_FILE=/phg/config.txt
phg_sif=/workdir/lcj34/liquibase_debug/phg_38.sif

singularity exec \
        -B ${WORKING_DIR}/:/phg/ \
        "$phg_sif" \
        /tassel-5-standalone/run_pipeline.pl -Xmx100G -debug -configParameters ${DOCKER_CONFIG_FILE} \
        -LiquibaseUpdatePlugin -command status -endPlugin > liquibaseUpdate_singularity_output.txt
```

How can I get Singularity to access the correct java?

Comment: What is the value of the JAVA_HOME environment variable?

Comment: Brilliant! ... it is set to /usr/local/jdk1.8.0_45 on the machine.  I have unset it and the problem (at least this one) is solved.  Thank you!